# "Parallel translate" of a geodesic in the following sense

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Since I'm lazy, I'm shamelessly referring to the following question:

[Derivative of Exponential Map](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/50712/derivative-of-exponential-map)

Given a Riemannian manifold $M$, let $\gamma: (a,b) \to M$ be a geodesic and $E$ a parallel vector field along $\gamma$. Define $\phi: (a,b) \to M$ by $t \mapsto \exp_{\gamma(t)}(E(t))$.

I completely agree, as Michael Pauley answered, that $\phi'(t)$ is nothing but $J_t(1)$, where $J_t$ is the Jacobi field with $J_t(0)=\gamma'(t), \nabla_{\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{u}}} {J_t}(0)=0$. But what is $\nabla_{\phi'(t)} {\phi'(t)}?$

Notice that, we can think of $\phi(t)=J_t(1)$  as a "parallel translate" of the geodesic $\gamma(t)$. Indeed in the Euclidean spaces or their quotient spaces, the answer is $\nabla_{\phi'(t)} {\phi'(t)}=0$, and the "parallel translate" is a geodesic, which is a staright line in Euclidean space. But what can we say if we work with general manifolds?

I've two questions:

1) Are there milder conditions on the manifold, than being Euclidean, that can guarantee that $\phi(t)$is a geodesic?

2) Are there computations that could relate $\nabla_{\phi'(t)} {\phi'(t)}$ to $\gamma, J,  R$, $R$ being the curvature tensor, which I'm assuming will arise in the expression.

You may ignore the rest.

What I tried to do so far, without much success:

On P. 174, Lemma 10.1 of of John Lee's Riemannian manifolds and curvature book (available for free download online), I tried to put $V=S$ and used the symmetry lemma: $D_s{T}=D_t{S}$ to obtain:

$D_s^2 (T) - D_t(D_s(S)) = R(S,T)S$. Note that $D_s(S)(s=1,t)=\nabla_{\phi'(t)} {\phi'(t)}$. But that's how far I'm only getting!

Thanks for your answers/inputs!

Comment: If $\phi$ is a geodesic for all $\gamma$ and $E$ then $M$ is flat.

Comment: Prof. Petrunin, do you mind giving me some pointers in the direction of the proof of your statement? I'd guess the proof might be a bit ugly, but I'd appreciate to be told what're the steps.

By the way, I think you've meant all the transverse curves are geodesics as well (apart from the geodesics in the geodesic variation curves)?

Thanks!

Comment: You should try to work it out yourself using either holonomy or Jacobi fields

Comment: I'd like to point out that if my Riemannian Manifolds book is "available for free download online," it is an illegal pirated copy. The copyright is owned by Springer, who has not given anyone permission to post it online.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that! By the way, I've to admit that I LOVED your book for its clear explanation and I do have the original copy myself! Also, I'd be happy (and am sure many others too) if you write a "second course" book on Riemannian Geometry, including all the comparison theorems, Böchner techniques etc.